# html form validation using thymeleaf not working spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am unable to catch any validation in html form using thymleaf template.

Form Object -

```
public class TestForm {
....
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]*", message = "Only characters")
    private String field1;
....
getter/setters
}
```

html code -

```
<div id="main">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${testForm}" method="post" >
                <div>
                    <label> Field1:</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="${testForm.field1}" name="field1" />
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('field1')}" th:errors="*{field1}">errors</div>
                </div>                  
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />          
            </form> 
        </div>
```

controller -

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
public String createTest(@Valid @ModelAttribute("testForm") TestForm testForm, MultipartHttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
        return "createtestform";
```

No error is thrown and form gets submitted successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the trouble because you placed BindingResult incorrect.
Replace it with MultipartHttpServletRequest, it must be **after** the validating parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
public String createTest(@Valid @ModelAttribute("testForm") TestForm testForm,  BindingResult bindingResult, MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
    return "createtestform";
```

Comment: It is. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is the most ridiculous solution I've ever seen, but it works perfectly.
Can someone please explain why the order of the method parameters are important in here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the other action?  From this `<form action="#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${testForm}" method="post" >` to this `<form th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${testForm}" method="post" >`?

Two more ideas.
1.  Maybe your `javax.validation.Pattern` got overridden somewhere?
2.  Have you tried removing the `@ModelAttribute("testForm")`?  So your method signature will be `public String createTest(@Valid TestForm testForm, MultipartHttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException`.