# Spring MVC Unable to pass form data using dropdown Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am playing around with Thymeleaf and have created a dropdown menu with people's names on it. My controller class represents a single user, which also has a sibling name with the user. 
When making the form, in Thymeleaf, the `th:field="*{sibling}"` is causing my issue and I am unable to resolve this. 
I have looked at SO links such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726525/thymeleaf-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-person-a) , however this did not help me to fix my problem. 
Directly below is the stack trace of the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at 
    ........
```

This is the code that I have produced, so far, which has currently been unsuccessful. The SO post I followed suggested that I include `BindingResult` but even with that, still no luck. 
I feel like I am missing something somewhat obvious but cannot think of a solution!

**EDIT**: Following [bphilipnyc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192465/bphilipnyc)'s advice, I have added user object to the model in my controller, which allows the dropdown list to render. However, the dropdown list does not populate at all.

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String userName;
    private String sibling;
   //getters and setters below
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    Set<String> allSiblings = new HashSet<>();

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public Recipe defaultInstance() {
        User user = new User();
        return user;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        List<User> allUsers = userService.findAll();
        createDropDown();

        model.addAttribute("users", allUsers);
        model.addAttribute("allSiblings", this.allSiblings);
        return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/search")
public String search(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("There was a error "+bindingResult);
        return "index";
    }

    System.out.println(user.getSibling());
    return "result";
}

private void createDropDown(){
    allSiblings.add("john");
    allSiblings.add("paul");
}
```

And finally I have an index.html page which has the following thymeleaf dropdown form:

```
<form style="display:inline-block" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${user}">
<select th:field="*{sibling}">
    <option value=""> --</option>
    <option th:each="ing : ${allSiblings}"
            th:value="${ing}"
            th:utext="${ing}">

    </option>
</select>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: You need to add the `user` object to the model in your controller.  You're referencing it with `th:object="${user}"` on the HTML page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069958/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request)

Comment: I figured out what you mean, and added in the user object to the model in my controller - it worked! thanks